# Highcharts chart won't load

Tags: highcharts, getjson

I'm trying to make a Highcharts line chart with data from an SQLite3 db. Unfortunately, the chart won't load. The output from tempdata.php is:
[[1,12.8],[2,12.9],[3,12.8],[4,12.4]...etc

How do I get the chart to load with this data?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("tempdata.php", function(json) {

            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'line',
                    marginRight: 130,
                    marginBottom: 25
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Id'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Temperature'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                            this.x +': '+ this.y;
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -10,
                    y: 100,
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: json
            });
        });

    });

});

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Order or operation error, you are loading the script that is supposed to display the chart prior to actually loading highcharts.js.

To fix it load highcharts.js just after jQuery but before you actually use it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is problem:

```
series: json
```

while should be:

```
series: [{ 
    data: json
}]
```

Comment: I changed this and I also placed the src=highcharts.js at the beginning of the js code. Still not working.

I tried loading the tempdata.php in the browser, but it gives me a 404 error. It runs fine when running it by using php5-cgi though.

Comment: If you are using Chrome, make sure your server works, otherwise Chrome doesn't allow to use AJAX on local files.